# System Requirements for KDE KWin on 4K monitors

Tags: nvidia, kde, kwin, 4k-monitor

I'm interested in buying a [24'' 4K monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L940OMY) and apply **2.0 scaling** for a much crispier, and easier on the eyes, desktop experience using a UHD monitor to display a HD desktop.

I won't do any gaming (it's my workstation at work).

I'm buying a new graphics-card (NVIDIA GeForce GTX750 Ti 2GB) that I can buy for 120$ in order to have a DisplayPort output, required to have 60Hz at 4K.

However, I have no idea about how demanding KDE at 4K scaled up to match 1920x1080 is, as KWin uses a 3D scenegraph.

I'd like to avoid buying a graphics card to later find out that I should have bought a stronger one.

Does anyone have some experience to share?

Thanks a lot